# Websocket closed with status code: 1006 issue

Tags: blazor-server-side

i use Razor components(Blazor Server side), and when my connection lost and appear again, it gives "Websocket closed with status code: 1006" error and doesnt work until page refresh.

i want to know how to make connection connected if this error apear?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a current short coming of Razor Components. There isn't currently a way to manage the disconnect and re-connect events of the SignalR hub.

However, there is a fix for this coming in the next preview (preview 4). You can view the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7537) for further details.